# Using JQuery, how can two HTML classes with the same class name be linked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, click

Using Javascript/ Jquery, how can two classes with the same class name be linked ?  When one is clicked the content of the matching class name will display.

```
  <div class="menu">
  <div>
  <a class="about link" href=#>About</a> //this is the  button to click
     </div>
    <div><a class="service link" href=#> Service</a> </div></div>

    <aside class="overlay about"> About section</aside> //the content will display depending on which button was pressed
    <aside class="overlay service"> Services </aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".link").click(function() {
   var currentSelector = (typeof($(this).attr('id')) !== 'undefined' || $(this).attr('id') !== null) ? '#' + $(this).attr('id') :  '.' + $(this).attr('class');
   $(".overlay"+ currentSelector).show();
});
```

Apparently, $(this).selector is deprecated since v1.7

Comment: No, because I wanted to use $(".link").click(function(){ ... and then link the a "about" with aside "about". The a that is clicked will match the overlay. I tried to use (this) but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.about').click(function() {
    $('aside.about).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('document').ready(function(){

  $('.about link').click(function(){

   $('.overlay about').show();

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="menu">
  <div>
  <a class="about link" href=#>About</a> //this is the  button to click
     </div>
    <div><a x-target="service" class="link" href=#> Service</a> </div></div>

    <aside class="overlay about"> About section</aside> //the content will display depending on which button was pressed
    <aside class="overlay service"> Services </aside>




$(".link").click(function() {
   var currentSelector = $(this).attr("x-target");
   $(".overlay ."+ currentSelector).toggle(); //Show if hidden and hide if visible
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a common class name to perform this action I like to explicitly set the target as a data attribute on the clicked element. You'll need to define an ID on the content to be shown and on the clicked element (not a bad thing) but I find it makes things more obvious as to how things are working.

It's how framework's like Bootstrap do it. They are often good examples to follow.

Example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu">
    <div>
        <a id='about-button' data-target='#about-content' class="about link" href=#>About</a> //this is the  button to click
    </div>
    <div>
        <a class="service link" href=#> Service</a>
    </div>
</div>
<aside id='about-content' class="overlay about"> About section</aside> //the content will display depending on which button was pressed
<aside class="overlay service"> Services </aside>
```

**Javascript/jQuery**

```
$('#about-button').click(function() {
    $($(this).data('target')).show(); // find the target using the stored data attribute
});
```